# How can I use git-svn together with Github, and avoid conflicts?

Tags: git, svn, wordpress, git-svn, git-rebase

I am using Git for my SCM of a WP Plugin. But of course I then have to commit it to an svn repo for it to be displayed in the WordPress Plugin Directory.  I have written [a guide](http://catn.com/wordpress/using-git-for-wordpress-development-scm-instead-of-subversion/) on how to do this so you can see the steps I am using for it.

Whenever I am about to commit to the svn, I do a `git rebase trunk` to update the svn trunk before the `git svn dcommit`.  However, if I pull from GitHub and then do the rebase I get conflict errors on all of the commits that have been done by someone else.

What is the reason, and what can I do here?

Because the conflicts are always on all of the commits by another author this gives me the idea that there should be another command (something like rebase) that I should run before `git rebase trunk` that will merge these files properly or something.

Comment: Tried `git svn rebase` but that produces the same errors.

Comment: +1 for writing a git-svn guide. There are a few out there already but yours looks pretty good based on a quick skim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that instead of `pull`ing from Github, you want to `fetch` from Github. A `git pull` is equivalent to a `git fetch` then a `git merge`, and git-svn doesn't play well with git merges.